# Continuity of function on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm currently taking my first course in Complex analysis and both the lectures and textbook have very minimal examples and it has been extremely frustrating.

Prove that f is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$ when:
$$f(z) = \bar{z}$$

Would I be able to use the Cauchy_Riemann Theorem to prove that this is holomorphic and in turn say that it is continuous?

Let $u(x,y) = x$ and $v(x,y) = -iy$.

Therefore, $u_x = 1 , v_y = -i$.
Showing that $u_x \neq v_y$.

This shows that the function is not continuous.

Thank you for any guidance.

P.S If anyone has any recommendations on books on undergraduate Complex analysis with a lot of examples please let me know.

Comment: The function is not holomorphic, but it is continuous. In fact, the $Re(f)$ and $Im(f)$ are continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I actually read in the text that it is continuous however I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: I think you need to prove the continuity by definition since the holomorphic conditions are much stronger than continuity.

Comment: hint: Compare $|z-w|$ to $|\overline z-\overline w|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A complex-valued function is continuous if and only if both, its real part and its imaginary part are continuous.

$f$ sends $$x+iy\mapsto x-iy$$

$f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $u,v$ are real valued functions.

$u(x,y)=x$ is continuous and $v(x,y)=-y$ is also continuous so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Okay just to clarify my understanding. If I had $f(z) = Re(z^3)$, it is continuous because $x^3$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, If $z=x+iy$, then $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$. In your case $f(z)=Re(z^3)=Re(x^3-3xy^2+i(3x^2y-y^3))=x^3-3xy^2$, since polynomial is continuous, yes $f(z)=Re(z^3)$ is continuous.  Note: $x^3\neq Re(z^3)$, see the calculation above. @Safder

Comment: @Safder If it clears your doubt, you may consider this as an accepted answer.

Comment: That makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: This is not really correct. The real part is not $x\mapsto x$, it is $x + iy\mapsto x$. With some abuse of notation, it can be thought of as $(x,y)\mapsto x$. Similarly for the imaginary part. It is the continuity of *these* maps that makes the original map continuous.

Comment: @MPW  I have edited. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok +1. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

We have $|f(z)-f(z_0)|=|\overline{z-z_0}|=|z-z_0| \to 0$ when $z\to 0$. ($|\overline{Z}|=|Z|$).